# Is it possible to use dynamic properties to save repeat sorting code across sibling classes?

Tags: swift, sorting, optimization

I have multiple classes that all inherit from `RootClass`

`RootClass` has a class function that returns an array of all instances of that class, called `fetchAll()`

So to get an array of all instances of a subclass, the code would be:
`let subclass1Array = SubClass1.fetchAll()`

Now I am making a custom function that wraps this, but sorts the array before returning

```
let allSubObjects1 = try! SubClass1.fetchAll()
let sortedSubObjects1 = allSubObjects1.sorted {
    if $0.prop1 == $1.prop1 {
        return $0.prop2 ?? "" < $1.prop2 ?? ""
    } else {
        return $0.prop1 ?? "" < $1.prop1 ?? ""
    }
}
return sortedSubObjects1
```

So here's the potential code optimization:
I currently have ~10 subclasses of `RootClass`, however each subclass has **different property names**

So Instead of prop1 and prop2, it could be propA and propB

**This means that there are ~10 functions which are logically the same, but the property names within the `sorted` closure are different**

now I was thinking of doing something like a `valueForKey` from my Objective-C days, and passing in the names of the properties before-hand, but I never really liked that technique as you have to use strings, which the compiler will never catch.

Is there a better way to do this?

Bonus problem, some of the subclasses actually need to sort with 3 properties,

```
if $0.prop1 == $1.prop1 {
    if $0.prop2 == $1.prop2 {
        return $0.prop3 ?? "" < $1.prop3 ?? ""
    } else {
        return $0.prop2 ?? "" < $1.prop2 ?? ""
    }
} else {
    return $0.prop1 ?? "" < $1.prop1 ?? ""
}
```

**In an ideal world, I have 1 function that takes an array of N number of properties to sort on, `[prop1, prop2]` or `[prop1, prop2, prop3]` and then it will just return a sorted array of these `RootClass` subclasses**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Approach 1 (Code below):

- Create a property called `sortWeight` that each class can have a custom implementation
- So each class determines how it needs to be sorted

## Approach 2:

- `Keypath` (`Swift` Equivalent of `valueForKey`)
- Refer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keypath

## Root Class:

```
class RootClass : CustomStringConvertible {

    var prop1 : Int

    init(prop1: Int) {

        self.prop1 = prop1
    }

    var description: String {

        return String(prop1)
    }

    var sortWeight : Int {

        return prop1
    }
}
```

## ClassA

```
class ClassA : RootClass {

    var prop2 : Int

    init(prop1: Int, prop2: Int) {

        self.prop2 = prop2

        super.init(prop1: prop1)
    }

    override var sortWeight : Int {

        return (prop2 * 10 + prop1)
    }

    override var description: String {

        return "(\(prop1), \(prop2))"
    }
}
```

## Invoking:

```
print("RootClass:")

var array : [RootClass] = [RootClass(prop1: 15), RootClass(prop1: 6), RootClass(prop1: 12)]

array.sort(by: { $0.sortWeight < $1.sortWeight })

print(array)

print("\nSubclass:")

array = [ClassA(prop1: 8, prop2: 3), ClassA(prop1: 4, prop2: 2)]

array.sort(by: { $0.sortWeight < $1.sortWeight })

print(array)
```

## Output:

```
RootClass:
[6, 12, 15]

Subclass:
[(4, 2), (8, 3)]
```